# Why does each element in this array of objects get overwritten by the last object?

Tags: java, arrays, class, object

I have the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Player players[] = new Player[2];
  Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Enter Player 1's name");
  players[0] = new Player(kb.nextLine());
  System.out.println("Enter Player 2's name");
  players[1] = new Player(kb.nextLine());
  System.out.println("Welcome "+ players[0].getName() + " and " + players[1].getName());    
}
```

It is meant to create a new player object and store the name of the player, while keeping all the objects in the array.

Here is the player class:

```
public class Player {
  static String name;
  public Player(String playerName) {
    name = playerName;
  }

  public String getName(){
    return name;
  } 
}
```

What actually happens is that it works when I just have 1 object, but when I have 2, each element in the array is the same as the second. When I have 3 objects in the array, each element is the same as the 3rd, etc.

I'm not sure why this is happening, or how to correct it, and it's been baffling me for hours :/

Comment: Guess what `static` means?

Comment: @JanDvorak ah nice catch, I was staring at this and was about to comment that the code looks fine.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Its because of the static field. Statics are used across object instances. They are stored at class level.

Below code would work:

```
class Player
{
    String name;

    public Player(String playerName)
    {
        name = playerName;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps the OP meant to use private instead of static?

Answer (score 4):

Change static string name to private string name

Answer (score 3):

Name field should not be static. Static means that the variable is actually global and shared across all class instances.

Answer (score 0):

With the keyword **static** you have made `name` a class variable which is **NOT** an instance variable. A class variable is common to all the objects. [Click for some more reading](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html).